# Qt get children from layout

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-designer

I try to hide all widgets in layout. But looks like `findChildren` doesn't 
work for layout.

Here's my sample code:

```
QLayout * layout = widget -> findChild<QLayout *> (layoutName);
QList<QWidget *> list = layout -> findChildren<QWidget *> ();

cout << list.size() << endl;
```

`size` is 0, but inside this layout I have a few widgets.
But the same code works fine if I try to get widgets from parent widget.

How I can get them from appropriate layout?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The layout does not "inject" itself in the parent-child tree, so the widgets stay (direct) children of their parent widget.

You could use `QLayout::count()` and `QLayout::itemAt()` instead.

Comment: The key point is that a layout can become a child of a widget (because they both inherit `QObject`), but a widget cannot become a child of a layout. A widget must have another widget as a parent, and `QLayout` does not inherit `QWidget`. Layouts wrap each item they contain in a [`QLayoutItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlayoutitem.html#QLayoutItem), and so a different set of APIs is required to access the underlying object.

Comment: Sucks that this comment is four years old. The way Qt even today makes QLayout keep track of the widgets inside it, is the private d_ptr and its list property. No public API...

Answer (score 44):

You can simply iterate over the layout's items, using `itemAt()`, then test whether the item is a widget:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gridLayout->count(); ++i)
{
  QWidget *widget = gridLayout->itemAt(i)->widget();
  if (widget != NULL)
  {
    widget->setVisible(false);
  }
  else
  {
    // You may want to recurse, or perform different actions on layouts.
    // See gridLayout->itemAt(i)->layout()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

It's very late but if anyone finds here like me, here is my solution:
I tried @braggPeaks answer(it's same as @Frank Osterfeld answer) but it failed. Then I modified like this and it works like a charm. (I have no idea why it works, because my layout has no null items but still I have to check if it has.)

```
for (int i = 0; i < this->layout->count(); ++i) {
    QWidget *w = this->layout->itemAt(i)->widget();
    if(w != NULL)
        w->setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: Must be implemented in subclasses to return the layout item at index. If there is no such item, the function must return 0. that's quoted from https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#itemAt

Answer (score 2):

Since layout is not part of widget hierarchy,  the widget has to be queried from parent but then indexOf can be used to see if it belongs and its location

```
  QLayout * top_l= layout(); // The parent widgets layout
   // Find your layout that you want to search inside
   QHBoxLayout * hbox = top_l->findChild<QHBoxLayout*>(QString("horizontalLayout_2"));
    if (hbox != 0) {
        std::cout << "Found horizontalLayout_2!"<<std::endl;
        QPushButton * st = findChild<QPushButton*>(QString("startButton"));

        if (st != 0) {
            std::cout << "Found startButton in top level widget"<<std::endl;
            int idx = hbox->indexOf(st);
            if (idx >=0) {
                std::cout << "Found startButton in hbox layout at location : "
                          <<idx<<std::endl;
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Responding to an old post, but I wanted a simple way to disable all widgets contained in a layout or any child-layout.  This worked for my purposes:

```
void setEnabledWidgetsInLayout(QLayout *layout, bool enabled)
{
   if (layout == NULL)
      return;

   QWidget *pw = layout->parentWidget();
   if (pw == NULL)
      return;

   foreach(QWidget *w, pw->findChildren<QWidget*>())
   {
      if (isChildWidgetOfAnyLayout(layout,w))
         w->setEnabled(enabled);
   }
}

bool isChildWidgetOfAnyLayout(QLayout *layout, QWidget *widget)
{
   if (layout == NULL or widget == NULL)
      return false;

   if (layout->indexOf(widget) >= 0)
      return true;

   foreach(QObject *o, layout->children())
   {
      if (isChildWidgetOfAnyLayout((QLayout*)o,widget))
         return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easier to create a QWidget as a container and put your widgets inside of that "container widget", this way you could access your widgets by calling `findChildren` on the "container widget":

```
auto children = ui->containerWidget->findChildren<QWidget *>();
for (auto child : children) {
    child->setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: In my case, there is already a groupbox as a parent of the horizontal layout. So changing ui->layout->findChildren to ui->groupBox->findChildren has solved.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try `children()` method instead of `findChildren()` ? Maybe you are getting a 'bad' layout from `widget -> findChild<QLayout *> (layoutName)` method. Try to find children right after creating the layout - so you are sure the layout is correct. Doing so you will be able do determine what function works wrong.

Comment: Yes I tried children(), without any luck. I can't check after creation, as this is loaded from .ui... For widgets works fine... Issue only with layout..