# C++ QT How to access a public class member of a QWidget from a QMainWindow Layout

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlayout

as the title says, i want to access the member variables of a class that inheritates of QWidget from a QGridLayout in a QMainWindow.
I am able to access member functions of the QWidget class, but i cant reach the members of my "Player" class.

I am aware, that "->widget()" returns just a QWidget*. Is there another way to return the real class, which sits at this coordinates?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16707157/6370737) shows just to access functions of the QWidget but not of classes inheritated of QWidget.

Code of the QMainWindow class:

```
...
for(int row = 0; row < rowsCount; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < colsCount; col++) {
       QWidget *player = this->ui->gridLayout->itemAtPosition(row, col)->widget();
       player->[HERE I WANT TO ACCESS THE PUBLIC MEMBER]
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I well understand you just have to dynamic cast your widget to a Player and check you really have a Player by security :

```
QWidget *widget = this->ui->gridLayout->itemAtPosition(row, col)->widget();
Player * player = dynamic_cast<Player *>(widget);

if (player != NULL) {
   ...
}
```